# Animated show (or movie) aimed at young girls. Blonde female with glove with green(ish) crystal

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I'm struggling to remember the name of an animated show (or movie?) that I watched around 2009-2012

The theme was broadly magical. One of the characters was a blonde woman with a greenish crystal outlined with gold on her hand or glove. The villain may have had a spiral on his stomach (not too sure). The main characters were teenage girls.

The show was in English and it seemed like it was aimed at younger girls, possibly those aged 5-10.

Comment: Roughly when did you watch it? What language was it in? Did it seem to be aimed at any particular age group?

Comment: It was most likely between 2009 and 2013. It was in English and it was aimed towards little girls who were maybe 5-10 years old.

Comment: Without more details, this seems to be too broad to answer. Please read [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Also: please don't write generic titles like "anybody know this show/movie?". You might as well write "question about thing"...

Comment: Can you remember anything else about the plot? SI questions are challenging to answer. The more details you provide the easier it'll be for someone to find an answer for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Image of three women with wings and dresses above cursive text reading “Sky Dancers”]
It was *Sky Dancers*!
It’s been so long since I heard of this show. Thanks for everyone’s help :)

Answer (score 2):

[Hyperdimension Neptunia](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/HyperdimensionNeptunia) had an animation commissioned named [Hyperdimension Neptunia the Animation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/HyperdimensionNeptuniaTheAnimation). Vert (or Green Heart) is a blonde-haired female with a green and gold motif to her costume, although her gloves are usually white, and without gems.

[image: Vert]

I also have not found any mention of a villain with a spiral on their stomach, and the Japanese version wasn't released until 2012, but I figured it was worth mentioning to see if it matches your memory.

Comment: Sorry fuzzy boots but that wasn't it. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've found it yet, but I think the show you're looking for is *[The New adventures of Ocean Girl](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0287253/)*.

[image: Poster for *The New Adventures of Ocean Girl*]

> On the planet of Oceana there were four life giving crystals guarded by the Sacred Whales, the keepers of wisdom. Thousands of years ago Galiel, the evil space wizard, stole one of the crystals. Now Princess Neri, must recover the crystal.

Comment: Why do you feel this is the right answer? I took the liberty of adding a description and image from your link.

Comment: Because it matches how Mackenzie described it

Comment: :) In what ways? I don't have the movie in question. Is there a blonde woman with a green crystal? A villain with a spiral on his stomach?

Comment: Sadly this isn’t the show :( thanks for trying tho